# When should Open Source and Milestone items in the profile be used?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, developer-story

I've some doubts with Open Source and Milestone items in the Developer Story tab of the profile (only where used for projects).

I see that they are used for adding projects to your profile, but there are some things that aren't specified, such as in which cases should they be used, so here are my questions:

Could you add...

- projects that you own?
- projects created by a team where you're the leader or one of them?
- projects created by a team to which you belong?
- projects where you are a maintainer?
- projects where you're actively contributing?
- projects where you sometimes contribute?
- projects that you had contributed to?
- projects that you like?

Maybe some of the cases are very at the extreme, but I wanted to ask from one extreme to other to have no doubt about that.

I also want to ask what does the start and end date represent.

- From the date you create to the date you delete the project or transfer ownership
- From the date you start to actively work on it to the date you stop actively working on it.
- From the date you started to work to the date you stopped checking out the project sometimes (maybe issues, pull requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who interviews a lot of developers that provide Stack Overflow profiles, I'd be happy with several of those items being listed on a Developer Profile. Remember, this is designed to help *you* get an job. You should assume that you'll be asked about anything on there, if you are providing the profile during the application. From my side of things, as a hiring manager, these provide a great opportunity to look at code samples, issue management, and ask you about those. It's also way more interesting for both of us if you are talking about a project you are passionate about versus a standard technical challenge interview question.

> projects that you own?

Definitely. You built this thing. If you are proud of it and it shows your skills, it should be added.

> projects created by a team where you're the leader or one of them?

Definitely. Development jobs, especially beyond Junior level ones, will involve some leadership skills.

> projects created by a team where you belong to?

This one can be tricky. If you are just a member of the team because someone invited you to a GitHub team, but can't show contributions, I'm going to count this against you when we talk. However, contributions don't only mean lines of code. Maintaining a project involves communication, issue triage, writing documentation and more. Team members can be doing any of those.

> projects where you are a maintainer?

Absolutely.

> projects where you're actively contrubution?

Absolutely.

> projects where you sometimes contribute?
> projects that you had contributed to?

Sure. I'd probably ask you about the type of contribution, but if you can talk about it and why that's a good step to start the conversation.

> projects that you like?

No. Your interests are good, but they don't show your skills. Remember, this is a job application where you should be showing off what you can do. It's not a time to say you like something.

Regarding start and end date, I recommend you pick an option that works for you. I don't recall ever asking about that specifically. I'm usually much more interested in the project itself. But, if you have dates be prepared to explain what they mean if you are asked.